# Importing data from a text file into a specific column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `system_settings` where there are 3 columns, namely `ID`, `Actual_Setting` & `Standards_Setting`.

In the `ID` column there are 3 rows, namely `'Virtual Machine 1'`, `'Virtual Machine 2'` & `'Virtual Machine 3'`.

I wish to import data from a text file into the column `'Actual_Setting'` where `ID = 'Virtual Machine 1'`.

I have tried using this query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL IN FILE 'C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin/syspolicy.txt'
INTO system_settings(Actual_Setting)
WHERE ID LIKE 'Virtual Machine 1';
```

but it returns an error.

I use MySQL Server 5.5, MySQL Query Browser & a Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 0):

[`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) will always insert data into *new* rows, not update an existing row.

However, in the event of a key collision, it can first *delete* the existing row through use of its `REPLACE` keyword. If there's a `UNIQUE` key on the `ID` column and you don't need to preserve the value of `Standards_Setting`, you can take advantage of this feature:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin/syspolicy.txt'
  REPLACE INTO TABLE system_settings
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY ''
  LINES STARTING BY '' TERMINATED BY ''
  (Actual_Setting)
  SET ID = 'Virtual Machine 1'
```

(Note that since you want to read the entire file into a single field, you must override the defaults and explicitly specify that there are no field or line termination/quoting/escaping characters.)

Otherwise, if you need to *update* the existing record, I'd suggest loading your file into a temporary table and then updating your table with the contents:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (content LONGTEXT);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin/syspolicy.txt'
  INTO TABLE foo
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY ''
  LINES STARTING BY '' TERMINATED BY ''
  (content);

UPDATE system_settings
  SET Actual_Setting = (SELECT content FROM foo)
WHERE ID = 'Virtual Machine 1';

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE foo;
```

Comment: @LamakDaruwala: I notice you unaccepted this answer; did it not solve your problem?